# tree generated from nltk tree.fromString not displaying left and right parenthesis in productions

Tags: nltk

```
t = nltk.Tree.fromstring(
"""
(NP
  (( ()
  (NNP Fetchez)
  (NNP la)
  (NNP vache)
  (. .)
  () ))
  (NN wha)
  (. ?))
"""
)

t.productions()
```

I am getting these productions as output

```
[NP ->  NN .,
  -> ,
  ->  NNP NNP NNP . ,
  -> ,
 NNP -> 'Fetchez',
 NNP -> 'la',
 NNP -> 'vache',
 . -> '.',
  -> ,
 NN -> 'wha',
 . -> '?']
```

These productions are missing the `(` and `)` on the rhs

```
 -> ,
 ->  NNP NNP NNP . ,
 -> ,
 -> ,
```

The correct productions would be something like this

```
 ( -> ,
 ( ->  NNP NNP NNP . ,
 ( -> ,
 ) -> ,
```

What is going on and how do I fix this or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that it works when doing a tree fromstring. This is actually a bug (not sure what this repo belongs to, but it's also described here: https://github.com/emilmont/pyStatParser/issues/4). I have usually worked around this by taking out any (round) brackets before parsing something with the nltk parser, quite tedious (consequently; if someone knows a better way around this/fix, I'd also be happy to hear about it :)